# Order of first/last-name for more than one author with amsrefs

Tags: bibliographies, amsrefs

I am using the `amsrefs` package with the `author-year` option. If I have two authors, I get in the reference for the author names the output:

> LAST NAME, FIRST NAME and FIRST NAME LAST NAME

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[author-year]{amsrefs}

\begin{document}
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}

\bib{SokalB1998}{book}{
 title={Fashionable Nonsense},
 subtitle={Postmodern Intellectuals’ Abuse of Science},
 author={Sokal, Alan},
 author={Bricmont, Jean},
 publisher={Picador USA},
 address={New York},
 date={1998}
 }

 \end{biblist}
 \end{bibdiv}
 \end{document}
```

Is there a way to get a more consistent output like:

> LAST NAME, FIRST NAME and LAST NAME, FIRST NAME

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The inversion for the first author is made just to ease looking up entries; the other authors don't need inversion.